# How to add pull-right to a Button in React Bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

I have the following JSX using React-Bootstrap:

```
<Button bsStyle="danger pull-right" bsSize="small" onClick={() => {alert('do stuff')}}>
    <Glyphicon glyph="trash" />
</Button>
```

This does work, but it shows a warning in the console:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `bsStyle` of value `danger pull-right` supplied to `Button`, expected one of `["success","warning","danger","info","default","primary","link"]`.

What is the best way to add `pull-right` to the list of styles? I'd prefer not to have any warnings in my console.

Comment: @AndrewLi bsClass is prepended to the value in bsStyle. This doesn't work.

Comment: How about using `className`?

Comment: That does indeed work! Answer the question and I'll mark it as answered :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you take a look at [React-Bootstrap Components](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html), you'll see that prop `bsStyle` of component `Button` only accepts the following values:

```
"success", "warning", "danger", "info", "default", "primary", "link"
```

based on its visual appearance as mentioned in the warning message. If you intend to use Bootstrap's `pull-right` class, just use the `className` attribute which will set the class of that component:

```
<Button className="pull-right" bsStyle="danger" bsSize="small" onClick={() => {alert('do stuff')}}>
    <Glyphicon glyph="trash" />
</Button>
```

Comment: and how to do it in react 4?

Answer (score 18):

### Bootstrap 4 Update

Now that React Bootstrap uses Bootstrap 4, use `float-right`, `float-sm-right`, etc.:

```
<Button className="float-right" bsStyle="danger" bsSize="small" onClick={() => {alert('do stuff')}}>
    <Glyphicon glyph="trash" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 17):

#### Bootstrap 5 Update

They changed the React Bootstrap after adoption of Bootstrap 5 and now *float-right* is **float-end** and *float-sm-right* is **float-sm-end**

```
<Button className="float-end" bsStyle="danger" bsSize="small" onClick={() => {alert('do stuff')}}>
   <Glyphicon glyph="trash" />
</Button>
```